# Angularjs limitTo not working in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am retrieving a search query from php mysql into my angularjs app. The results are in the following format:[image]

This object is then displayed in my angularjs app and displayed using ng-repeat. The thing is I would like to limit the results to 10 only. However for some reason it does not work. I did find a possible solution [limiTo not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350240/angularjs-ngrepeat-not-respecting-limitto-filter). Here it states LimitTo does not work if it is an object in an object. If this is the solution how would I convert srchResults to an object in an array in javascript?? If it is not what would be the issue?

I'm using Angular 1.3.11.

My code:

```
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="result in srchResults|limitTo:10" >
    <div class="md-list-item-text" ng-click= "getEmployee(result.employee_id)">
        <h3>{{result.last_name}}, {{result.first_name}}</h3>
        <h4>{{result.name}}</h4>
        <p>{{result.fk_cs_type}}, {{result.is_active==1?"Active":"In-Active"}}</p>
        <md-divider ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
    </div>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: your code is working fine. look for console.log output for errors. here is the jsfiddle of your code.http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/e02ky94p/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your query about

> how would I convert srchResults to an object in an array in javascript

to convert an "object of objects" to an "array of objects" you can do the following:

```
var obj; //your parent object
var res = [] //will stor result here

for(var i in obj) {
   res.push(obj[i]);
}
```

after loop ends, you will have `res` as your desired array

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant, if you know count fields you can use [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var data = {0:{a:1},1:{a:1},2:{a:1},3:{a:1},4:{a:1}}
```

we know that here 5 fields, so we can do

```
data.length = 5;
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(data);
```

```js
var data = {
   0: {
     a: 1
   },
   1: {
     a: 1
   },
   2: {
     a: 1
   },
   3: {
     a: 1
   },
   4: {
     a: 1
   }
 }


 data.length = 5;
 var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(data);

 console.log(data, arr);
```

Or we can a bit automate this

```js
var data = {
   0: {
     a: 1
   },
   1: {
     a: 1
   },
   2: {
     a: 1
   },
   3: {
     a: 1
   },
   4: {
     a: 1
   }
 }

 var keys = Object.keys(data);
 data.length = 1+ +keys[keys.length-1];
 var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(data);

 console.log(data, arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="(key,value) in srchResults|limitTo:11" >
    <div class="md-list-item-text" ng-click= "getEmployee(value.employee_id)">
        <h3>{{value.last_name}}, {{value.first_name}}</h3>
        <h4>{{value.name}}</h4>
        <p>{{value.fk_cs_type}}, {{value.is_active==1?"Active":"In-Active"}}</p>
        <md-divider ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
    </div>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: in your fiddle `srchResults` is _array_, in OP - is _object_ and `limitTo` work only with _array_

Comment: Since his screenshot showed an object, i made the code.That's why i made my answer that fits for object. But my jsfiddle will show both.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge that limitTo will not work with object.